# How to use countif based on multiple vlookup results

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, vlookup, countif

In Google Sheet, I am trying to count the number of responses received on several criteria.

1. All responses are tied to a specific event ID in Column A in sheet 1.
2. There are multiple respondents per event ID in sheet 2 in Column B. Each respondent has their own row. It shows their event ID in Column A.
3. Their response is on sheet 2 column C.

I am trying to figure out how many responses occurred per event. I have a feeling this countif formula might need a vlookup or match/index nested inside but I'm not sure how to construct it. Any help would be very appreciated.

[Example Sheet 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XS2tP.png)

[Example Sheet 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmmiI.png)

Comment: Can you provide sample data and expected output?

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=QUERY(Sheet2!A:C; "select A,count(B),count(C) where A is not null group by A"; 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
B1 Formula - COUNTIF($F$2:$F$9,A2)
C1 Formula - COUNTIFS($H$2:$H$9,"<>"&"",$F$2:$F$9,A2)
```

[image]